# Undefined error for field image

Tags: 7, media

I am using a custom image field in one of my content types, which I am accessing using the following code.

```
if ($content['field_heading']) { 
  print render($content['field_heading']);
}
```

Everything is fine, except that in administrative area I am seeing this error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: field_heading in include() (line 4 of tridz7\sites\all\themes\tridz\node.tpl.php).

What could be the reason? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have nodes where the "field_heading" field has not been set, or you didn't enable the field in output tab on content type section.

Try this code:

```
if (!empty($content['field_heading'])) { 
  print render($content['field_heading']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal errors "Notice: Undefined index: profile in..."](http://www.leveltendesign.com/solution/drupal-errors-notice-undefined-index-profile).

Basically the particular above notice is created when PHP tries to access the index of an array, where the variable is not holding an array. Check that 'field_heading' has a value assigned to it in the `$content` array.

If this is your development server, you'll also want to disable displaying warnings. The link above also details how you can do this at the PHP/server level; you can also [disable the error reporting to the screen on a production site in Drupal](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/disable-error-reporting-to-the-screen-on-a-production-site-in-drupal).